# No me presenta los datos en el Jtable en Java

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Tengo el siguiente codigo, trabajo con una Array y en diferentes clases, por medio de objetos, a la hora de querrer presentar mis personas en el Jtable, no los presenta.
Me falta declarar algo o necesito un codigo extra o lo tengo mal planteado.

```
public class FrmConsultaEST extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
         //DECLARA EL OBJETO
    ArLEst Are;
    DefaultTableModel dtm;   
    
        //CONSTRUCTOR
    public FrmConsultaEST() {
        initComponents();
            //INSTANCION EL OBJETO 
        Are = new ArLEst();
        dtm = (DefaultTableModel) this.jTable1.getModel();
    }

    private void BtnVerDatosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<Are.Tamaño(); i++){
                dtm.setRowCount(i+1);
                Estudiantes ListEST = Are.Leer(i);
                this.jTable1.setValueAt(ListEST.getCedula(), i, 0);
                this.jTable1.setValueAt(ListEST.getCODIGO(), i, 1);
```

Comment: Hola Edwin, sería de gran ayuda que adjuntes la clase lo más completa posible.

Comment: Podrías probar si **`ListEST.getCedula()`** y **`ListEST.getCODIGO()`** realmente devuelven algo.

Comment: Y eso como lo haria, estoy aprendiendo. Y no tengo claro la documentación.

Comment: Podes poner debajo de **`Estudiantes ListEST = Are.Leer(i);`**, una linea con **`System.out.println( "cedula = " + ListEST.getCedula() );`** y otra con **`System.out.println( "código = " + ListEST.getCODIGO() );`**, eso te imprime en la consola, el valor de ambas variables, que casi con seguridad será `cedula =` y `código =`, lo qe te indica que ambas variables están vacías... o no.